# Code completion not working in vim for ruby

Tags: ruby, vim

I am using mvim on Mac for programming in Ruby and have installed the rcodetools plugin for vim. On doing a C-X C-U i get the message completefunc is not set. I havent been able to figure out what completefunc should be set to. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `completefunc` setting should get set automatically to "RCT_completion" in rcodetools.vim:

```
if v:version >= 700
    execute "au Filetype ruby setlocal completefunc=" . s:sid . "RCT_completion"
endif
```

It sounds like the filetype of the buffer you're editing might not be "ruby".
You can check this by running the `:set ft?` command